# Does Mobogenie for Android install adware on the phone?

Tags: applications

Has anyone used Mobogenie? It looks like a very useful way to control an Android phone from a PC, but I found one review that says it installs adware in your browser. However, it wasn't clear if this was on the PC or on the phone.

Comment: What's your actual question? "Has anyone used x?" isn't a suitable question for this site, and I assume that's not actually what you want to know.

Comment: @DanHulme Rephrased the question

Comment: @geffchang Thanks for trying to help. I still intend to wait until we hear from the OP what he wants to know, rather than trying to guess.

Comment: Where did you see the review? Is it on Google Play, or a software review site [and which site]?